# How to read a cookie in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, httpcookie

I'm not sure how to read a web cookie in C#. I tried this code, but I get multiple errors.

```
        private string GetCookieValue(string cookieName, string itemName)
        {
            var CookieName = "MY_COOKIE";
            var CookieValue = string.empty;
                                //     ^ error

            HttpCookie myCookie = Request.Cookies[CookieName];
            // ^ error              // ^ error           
            if (myCookie == null) 

            {
                return "No Cookie Found.";
            }


            CookieValue = myCookie.Value.ToString();

            return CookieValue;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

(sorry about that) Errors:

line 4, 'string' does not contain a definition for 'empty'
line 5, the type or namespace name 'HttpCookie' could not be found.
line 5, The name Request does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Please be specific about the errors you are getting. It is often best just to cut and paste any error messages into the question.

Comment: Also, please show more of your code. Just with this tiny bit of code, it's difficult to tell what the errors are.

Comment: What type does your `Request` object have? Also `string.empty` should be either `string.Empty` or `""`

Comment: Are you sure there's a cookie in there titled "MY_COOKIE"? Set a breakpoint and inspect.

Comment: And actually, yeah, what errors are you getting? You need to be more specific and provide details.

Comment: @Jonathan

I added the errors. Sorry about that!

Comment: @thebear8

I added the errors. Sorry about that!

Comment: @JohnWu
I added the errors. Sorry about that!

Comment: Just to be sure: you are doing this in a web project, are you? And in code-behind or controller?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing No, I'm not doing this in a web project. I'm doing this in a C# windows forms app.

Comment: A windows forms app doesn't use cookies or requests. It also cannot access cookies stored by some browser on your system. Or are you doing an http call to some website from your app? Why exactly are you trying to use cookies here?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I am trying to use cookies to communicate the web browser to my C# program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use string.Empty and not empty. For reading of cookie, see below example:

```
public static string GetFromCookie(string cookieName, string keyName)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        //Logic placeholder
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That worked for one error. I still have 2 more. (the ones on line 5) but Thanks!

Comment: if the application needs to interact with ASP.NET Session, or with cookies then we can use System.Web.HttpContext....make sure you are referring to the correct Request object.

Comment: When I try to do System.Web it only gives me 3 options, look at the picture: imgur.com/a/iujABZs

Comment: Can you check your dependencies? System.Web should be there. Just add dll library called "System.Web". https://pasteboard.co/J67Pbdh.png